# Date class misbehaves in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby

***Ruby version: `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]`***

Why does below code able to create `Date` object but unable to invoke a valid method on it?

**Code version 1**

```
p d = Date.new  # Works fine - Prints - #<Date:0x000000027aa628>
p Date.gregorian_leap?(2016) # undefined method `gregorian_leap?' for Date:Class (NoMethodError)
```

**Code version 2** Above code works fine if we add `require` statement

```
require 'date'
p d = Date.new  # Prints #<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
p Date.gregorian_leap?(2016) # Prints true
```

Which `Date` class is getting instantiated in version 1 above?  Does Ruby have concept of fully qualified class name which we can inspect to find the difference in two cases?

---

***Ruby version: `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]`***

In `Ruby 2.2`, `Date.new` fails early - does not misbehave like Ruby 2.0 did

```
p d = Date.new # uninitialized constant Date (NameError)
p Date.gregorian_leap?(2016) # did not reach here, previous line errored out
```

Comment: It's because Ruby 2.0 had an empty `Date` class for compatibility reasons.
Look here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9890

Comment: @MarekLipka  I have posted your answer as "Community wiki" answer - if you wish to earn reputation points for your answer, please post your entry as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by Marek Lipka (in comments section),

> It's because Ruby 2.0 had an empty Date class for compatibility
>   reasons.
>
> Reference: [bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9890](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9890)